# Отображение лишнего значка на HTML странице проекта

Tags: css3, html5

В Django проекте при создании какого-либо HTML файла в конце страницы всегда появляется данный значок,пробовал в разных браузерах,все равно остается.Только  осваиваю HTML, CSS и не знаю с чем это может быть связано,как избавиться от данной картинки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello Django</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: добавьте Ваш код

Answer (score 1):

Я смотрю у вас Chrome, Нажмите F12, откроется отладчик

Перейдите на закладку **Elements** и нажмите на кнопку **(1)**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем на странице выделите картинку **(2)** мышкой

И увидите его в разметке **(3)**

Comment: <img src="https://gif-ads.top/click.php?cnv_u=496951">
Вот тег для данной картинки

Comment: ну нет там картинки, у меня пустой ответ приходит с этого урл

Comment: @БогданМарченко похоже на работу расширения для браузера или еще чего-то ткое

Comment: Богдан, в вашем браузере сидит какашка, позволяющая нечестным способом зарабатывать на браузерных расширениях, скрытно загружая рекламу. Проверьте плагины и  удалите ненужные. Пройдите компьютер антивирусом и адвклинером/антималваре. На крайний случай - переустановите браузер.